Mutable borrow on extended trait
I have a vector of dynamic dispatch references that implement an extended trait. I would also like to be able to pass them in to a function that accepts the base trait:
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;

trait MyTrait {
    fn doit(&mut self);
}

trait MyOtherTrait: MyTrait {
    fn doit_too(&mut self);
}

fn doit<T>(items: &mut [T])
where T: BorrowMut<dyn MyTrait>
{
    for item in items.iter_mut() {
        item.borrow_mut().doit();
    }
}

struct A {}

impl MyTrait for A {
    fn doit(&mut self) { println!("AAAAA!"); }
}

impl MyOtherTrait for A {
    fn doit_too(&mut self) { println!("22222!"); }
}

fn main() {
    let mut boxes: Vec<Box<dyn MyOtherTrait>> = vec![A{}, A{}, A{}].into_iter().map(|a| Box::new(a) as Box<dyn MyOtherTrait>).collect();
    doit(&mut boxes);
    for item in boxes.iter_mut() {
        item.doit_too();
    }
}

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<dyn MyOtherTrait>: BorrowMut<(dyn MyTrait + 'static)>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main-dyn.rs:31:10
   |
31 |     doit(&mut boxes);
   |     ---- ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorrowMut<(dyn MyTrait + 'static)>` is not implemented for `Box<dyn MyOtherTrait>`
   |     |
   |     required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `BorrowMut<dyn MyOtherTrait>` is implemented for `Box<dyn MyOtherTrait>`
note: required by a bound in `doit`
  --> src/main-dyn.rs:12:10
   |
11 | fn doit<T>(items: &mut [T])
   |    ---- required by a bound in this function
12 | where T: BorrowMut<dyn MyTrait>
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `doit`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `scratchpad` (bin "dyn") due to previous error

Where is the lifetime requirement 'static coming from? How can I process the vector of MyOtherTrait boxes as MyTrait?
For reference, I have tried to make a second vector Vec<&mut dyn MyTrait> from boxes, but that results in multiple mutable borrows when I call the function.

Box<dyn Trait> is shorthand for Box<dyn Trait + 'static>

@cafce25. What is 'static for? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how lifetimes work here.

The static lifetime. and the trait object needs to be bound by it unless you specify another bound.

OIC. So the trait itself is bound by that, not the object that is in the box?

Regardless of lifetimes (which can be fixed by including a generic 'a and annotating dyn MyTrait + 'a)... Box<dyn MyOtherTrait> does not implement BorrowMut<dyn MyTrait>. You can't even get a &dyn MyTrait from a &dyn MyOtherTrait, that "cast" is not inherently supported.

No, the trait object is bound by that.

Rel (or dupe?): Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting

@cafce25 Rel yes, dupe no.

You can relax your requirements in doit to this:
fn doit<T, U>(items: &mut [T])
where
    T: AsMut<U>,
    U: MyTrait + ?Sized,
{
    for item in items.iter_mut() {
        item.as_mut().doit();
    }
}

By not requiring it to give you dyn MyTrait directly, just anything that can produce a mutable reference to something that implements the trait, you can pass trait objects to things that implement a super trait as well.

This is exactly what I was looking for! TIL about AsMut

Also found AsRef. This is really great.

Also, the explanation of the lifetime was helpful. I actually got where the 'static came from
